# Securing Post Comment Like System

Tags: php, mysql, security

I have a PHP script that very much like a commenting system, but requires a confirmation of the suggested comment first.

Example:

1) User enters comment.
2) Users is sent to confirm page that displays comment and ask user to confirm it is correct.
3) User confirms and the comment is inserted into a database.

My questions is, which PHP functions are best to secure the display of the the comment on the confirm page, and then to insert it into a database. Do i also need something to secure it after fetching it from a database for display afterwards?

Comment: In what form do you mean "securing", as in XSS or more like authentication?

Comment: And also which package are you using to communicate with the database?

Comment: This is almost impossible to answer, I suggest you keep on reading about PHP and how certain levels of security are achieved with user inputed data.

Comment: @Luceos my knowledge of security issues is poor, but I'm just looking to avoid XSS/Injection type attacks. I understand security is a huge topic, but I'm looking for basic security for inserting into a MySQL table, and displaying afterwards.

Comment: @John; if you are using mysql_query; try to look into PDO for prepared statements if you worry about security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you talk about code security, one should always stick to the golden rules :

- **Filter** all input ( [filter_var()](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) or any framework included class)
- **Escape** all output ( at least [htmlspecialchars()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) )

There are many levels to secure a form, or an entire application. These two are just primers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused as to what you mean, but I'm assuming that you're trying to ensure against SQL injection? i.e; a user can't type in '; UPDATE users SET password = 'abc' WHERE user = 'admin'; etc?

If so, you're looking for http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php . Or mysql_real_escape_string() if you're using the deprecated functions.

Hope this helps - if not, please provide a little more clarification on what exactly you're looking for :)